# why different namespace of same room name sharing the data in both namespace

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

i'm trying to create a dynamic multiple namespace with

```
const nsp =io.of(/^\/organization-\d+s/)
```

dynamic namespace like

- organization-101
- organization-102

when i try to create a same room in both namespace like

- organization-101

  - random/room
- organization-102

  - random/room

when i pass the data to random room  in organization-101 the data is also passing to the random room in organization-102,
why this is happening.I don't want to pass the data the data between organization.
so please help me to understand, if not this is source code

```
    const nameSpace = io.of(/^\/organisation-\d+$/)
    nameSpace.on('connect', (socket) => {
              console.log('a user connected')
    socket.on('join', (data) => {
    socket.join(data.room) // do i mention the namespace here ?
        nameSpace
            .in(data.room)
            .emit('chat message', `New person joined the ${data.room} room`)
    })

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('user disconnected')
    })
 socket.on('chat message', (data) => {
        console.log('message: ' + data.msg)
        nameSpace.in(data.room).emit('chat message', data.msg)
    })})
```